# impala query failed to execute `date` command in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, impala

I have below imapala query run on shell script which is throwing error.

date with back quotes `date`

```
impala-shell -B -i $IMPALA_CON --ssl -q  "use db_test ; select concat(substring(`date`,3,2),substring(`date`,6,2),substring(`date`,9,2)) id from db_test.date_d where `date`<=cast(current_timestamp() as string)" -o $FILE/abc.txt '--output_delimiter=,'
```

> ERROR: ParseException: Syntax error in line 1:
> select concat(substring(Tue Jan 17 02:18:20 EST 2023,3,2...

Comment: Don't know what impala is but did you try putting the date in quotes? e.g. `substring('$(date)',3,2)`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting and then [edit] your question to format your input, output, and code as Code Blocks so it's clearer.

Comment: Now code is clearer. as my select statement is having date with back quotes that's failing while running command from shell script

Comment: Run `set -x` in your shell to enable logging so you can see what's actually run (you can disable it with `set +x`). You _will_ see the output from `date` substituted in, but if you read closely you'll also see why the resulting command isn't using valid database query syntax.

Comment: (if this is running from a script, you'll want `set -x` to be a prior command in the script, or you can run `bash -x yourscript`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date` is a shell command, and the backquotes are doing command substitution. You're getting the date substituted in without quotes around it. Try `` '`date`' `` instead of just `` `date` `` (note the single quotes around the backquotes).